# difference between [self.view release] and [view release]?

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between

difference between [self.view release] and [view release].

I get a memory leak error in [self.view release]

Comment: could you show some more code?

Answer (score 1):

`[view release]` is calling `NSObject`'s `- (void)release` method directly on an instance variable named `view`.

`[self.view release]` is calling `- (UIView *)view` (I'm assuming `view` is of type `UIView`) on `self` and *then* calling `- (void)release` on the returned object.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any practical difference. However, since one reason for using properties is to eliminate the need for explicit memory management, `[self.view release]` would be a strange thing to do. If it's a property, let the property accessors retain and release the object as necessary.

It's hard to see why you'd get a real leak from `[self.view release]`. Leaks come from failing to properly release an object -- I don't think you can create a leak by releasing something. It may be that accessing the object through a property prevents the static analyzer from connecting the dots from +alloc to -release.

Comment: Actually, `[self.view release]` is perfectly fine in `dealloc` method if the same class originally allocated the view.

Comment: @sergio: If it's a synthesized property, then I'd normally just say `self.view = nil;` and let the setter do the releasing. If you have access to the ivar, I'd normally use the ivar directly in your -init and -dealloc methods.

Comment: I see, but this does not imply that `[self.view release]` is a strange thing.